# How do you interpolate path in firestore rules functions?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying to DRY up my rules so I'm writing a function like this

```
function isInCollection(field, collection) {
  return exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/$(collection)/request.resource.data[field])
}
```

I've tried at least six permutations of this argument to `exists()` including using the `path()` function to construct a path out of a string and I can't get it to properly resolve the path. I'm suspicious that the issue is related to the `[]` notation around field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the same syntax as you're already using to interpolate `database` and `collection`.  Use `$()` to contain the expression you want to add to the path.

```
exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/$(collection)/$(request.resource.data[field]))
```

Comment: I've tried that and the simulator is still giving me an Argument error on the exists call. Is something wrong with my function call? It's `isInCollection("timetype","TimeTypes")`

Comment: The console simulator is known to have problems sometimes.  You should check first to see if it works when actually deployed.  If so, this is another bug in the simulator.  If there is still a problem, please edit the question to show the **entire** set of rules, not just this one function.

Comment: Nailed it. It works fine IRL, just an issue with the simulator. Thanks Doug, and also for the great YouTube videos!

Comment: Cool.  If you have to file a bug report about this, that would be helpful if you have time.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support